# Missing /amp in URL

Tags: wordpress, amp-html

About a month ago my URLs still had `/amp` in them on Google Analytics. The amp pages are still showing up on Google search, but when I look now on analytics the `/amp` is gone?

Example:

`website.com/blog/post-01/amp` - this was like a month ago on analytics
`website.com/blog/post-01/` - missing /amp now analytics

Basically the user still accesses the `/amp` page and it shows in the URL. But just not recorded as `/amp` in analytics. It gets recorded without the `/amp` part.

This is a wordpress site using:
Google Analytics Dashboard for WP (GADWP) and AMP by Automattic

Answer (score 0):

You may also check this [related thread](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmasters/K8xwJvcU6Hs;context-place=topicsearchin/webmasters/category$3Aaccelerated-mobile-pages-amp%7Csort:relevance%7Cspell:false) which stated that this seems like a sort of tracking param. Google probably use it internally for logging something (eg tracking clicks from serach results). You may also refer with this [related report](https://www.en.advertisercommunity.com/t5/Google-Analytics-Reports/Odd-AMP-page-URL-extension-coming-from-google-organic-traffic/m-p/1171689#).